# Create Association Model First With Ignoring Certain PKs

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following Table Structure

**Facility**

- PK Facility ID
- AccountID

**Accounts**

- PK NameID
- PK AccountID

I can't touch the DB so my changes need to be in Entity Framework.  Essentially the `AccountIDs` are linked so I want to create an association between them.  So when I create an association I map the `AccountIDs` together, however I can't map `FacilityID` to anything and `NameID` to anything so when I save Visual Studio complains that the mapping is not set correctly.

My main question is how do I ignore the mappings for `FacilityID` and `NameID`?  I've tried added `[NotMapped]` to both `FacilityID` and `NameID` but that does not work.  I've also tried creating a scalar property for `Facility` and `Accounts` and used the **Referntial Constraint** to map them however when I try to map the columns under Table Mapping, the columns I added do not show up which causes VS to complain as well.

Here is my table, I removed most of the fields because they are unnecessary 
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure but i think you are mistaking the concept of mapping, it's about the link between your entity object AND the database, so NameID should be mapped to NameID in your DB

Comment: I'm referring to the mapping between two tables.  It seems that PKs must be mapped when adding an association.  However, I do not want to map FacilityID & AccountID because there is nothing to map it to.

Comment: Can you share the DDL of the tables?  And what does "the mapping between two tables" mean?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Added the image above, the mapping between the two tables means the association I want to create between `AccountId` from `Facility` and `AccountID` from `Account`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Account.AccountID is unique (ie no two rows in Account actually have the same AccountID), just declare that as the only Key Property on the Account entity.

The Key of an entity does not have to be declared as the PK in the database.  But you can only have one Key per entity (the Key can, of course, have multiple columns, and EF Core does support alternate keys).  The entity Key should be unique, and should have a unique index in the database on the corresponding columns, but that's not enforced by EF.

Comment: What about `FacilityId` from `Facility`? VS still complains that Association End 'Facility' is not mapped.

Comment: Without DDL, no way to tell.  It's often easier to just use Code First and configure the mappings on the classes, skipping the EDMX entirely.